# SLF4J Warning - Loggers will not work as they were created during initialization phase

Tags: java, logback, slf4j, dropwizard

I am using slf4j with logback in a dropwizard application. During the application initialization I am seeing logs like below

```
SLF4J: The following loggers will not work because they were created
SLF4J: during the default configuration phase of the underlying logging system.
SLF4J: See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#substituteLogger
SLF4J: com.vnera.healthandmetrics.VneraMetrics
```

I am using `logback.xml` with my dropwizard application. My code flow looks like below

```
public class VneraMetrics {
   private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VneraMetrics.class);
 ...
 // This method is getting called from Service.run() during the dropwizard application initialization
 public String getSomeValue() {
     // logger is not accessed from this function
     return "Some initialized value";
 }
}

public class Service extends Application<Conf> {
   public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Service.class);
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      logger.info("Some logs");
      Service service = new Service();
      service.run(dropWizardArgs);
      Utils.reloadLogger();
   }
}
```

`Utils.reloadLogger()` is loading the loggback configuration as discussed here

```
public static void reloadLogger() {
        String loggingConfig = System.getProperty("logback.configurationFile");
        if(loggingConfig == null) {
            System.out.println("Logging Config is null");
        }

        LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        loggerContext.reset();
        JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();

        try {
            InputStream configStream = FileUtils.openInputStream(new File(loggingConfig));
            configurator.setContext(loggerContext);
            configurator.doConfigure(configStream); // loads logback file
            configStream.close();
            System.out.println("Loaded configuration file");
        } catch (JoranException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to log configuration file");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Versions**

- Logback - 1.2.3
- Dropwizard - 1.0.2

Can some one let me know what does the SLF4J warning denotes? I have seen the [substituteLogger](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#substituteLogger) page but this does not mention how can I get around this? On trying to use logger in `VneraMetrics` it is not printing anything.